# Missing c.h in Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode

Simple question really.. I'm just starting out programming with [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) and I'm creating a simple [ANSI C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_C) program and the Xcode book I'm reading says to include c.h because it defines true and false for you among other things. I don't have c.h though and I'm wondering if it's a big deal or not.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

c.h is not a standard header. Is it an include file defined in the book? Try removing the include and see if the code compiles.

Comment: the C99 header for boolean types is called `stdbool.h`; there's not really any need for it, though: compliant compilers will support the builtin type `_Bool`, which has the range `{0,1}`

Answer (score 0):

The book made out that it was a standard header. The only thing that it was used for was the definitions of true and false, so I defined them by hand like I guess everyone else does and compiled without it.